# Trying to call a cell value, why is my list of column values being interpreted as index values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, series

I need to do some maths using the following dataframe. In a for loop iterating through VALUE column cells, I need to grab the corresponding FracDist.

```
    VALUE  FracDist
0      11  0.022133
1      21  0.021187
2      22  0.001336
3      23  0.000303
4      24  0.000015
5      31  0.000611
6      41  0.040523
7      42  0.285630
8      43  0.161956
9      52  0.296993
10     71  0.160705
11     82  0.008424
12     90  0.000130
13     95  0.000053
```

First I made a list of VALUE values which I can use in a for loop, which worked as expected:

```
IN: LCvals = df['VALUE'].tolist()
    print LCvals
OUT: [11, 21, 22, 23, 24, 31, 41, 42, 43, 52, 71, 82, 90, 95]
```

When I try to grab a cell from the dataframe's FracDist column based on which VALUE row the for loop is on, that is where a problem comes up. Instead of looking up rows using VALUE from the VALUE column, the code is trying to lookup rows using VALUE as the index. So what I get:

```
IN:    for val in LCvals:
            print val
            print LCdf.loc[val]['FracDist']

OUT:    11
        0.00842444155517
        21
        KeyError: 'the label [21] is not in the [index]'
```

Note that the FracDist row that is grabbed for VALUE=11 is from index 11, not VALUE 11.

What needs to change in that for loop code to query rows based on VALUE in the VALUE column rather than VALUE as a spot in the index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `pd.DataFrame.loc` will index first by row label and then, if a second argument is supplied, by column label. This is by design. See also [Indexing and Selecting Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html).

Don't, under any circumstances use chained indexing. For example, Boolean indexing followed by column label selection via `LCdf.loc[LCdf['VALUE']==val]['FracDist']` is not recommended.

If you wish to iterate a single series, you can use [`pd.Series.items`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.items.html). But here you are using `'VALUE'` as if it were an index, so you can use `set_index` first:

```
for val, dist in df.set_index('VALUE')['FracDist'].items():
    print(val, dist)

11 0.022133
21 0.021187
...
90 0.00013
95 5.3e-05
```

Comment: I might've accepted this too soon! Running this, I get the error: `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'items'` and if I remove .items I get `TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable` which I presume is referring to an issue with VALUE vals.

Comment: I needed `.iteritems()` instead of `.items()`. Now it's working!

Comment: @cr0, Yep, I think that's to do with Pandas version potentially. I've added a link to the docs.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass in an integer into `.loc`, it will return (in this case) a value located at that index. You could use this `LCdf.loc[LCdf['VALUE']==val]['FracDist']`.

Edit: Here is a better (more efficient) answer:

```
for index, row in LCdf.iterrows():
    print(row['VALUE'])
    print(row['FracDist'])
```

Comment: While this answer got me back on track in the simplest form, I'm marking the other as accepted since it pointed me toward some key concepts I wasn't aware of yet which will help me through the rest of this program. Thanks anyway!